# Residual voltage?

Tags: capacitor

Does this use capacitors?

I ask because I added an inline switch to the side with incoming 120 V A.C.

With the switch off, there was still voltage present in the output side.

I hooked up a led, turned the switch on, then off and it glowed for about 20 seconds and then faded off.

[image]

Comment: What LED spec?..... looks like you overloaded the PTC shutdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old-style unregulated "wall wart" adapter. The internal circuit is probably this, and nothing more:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f860eF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transformer is designed to fail in a safe manner (no external flames, not too much smoke and isolation between mains and output maintained) if it develops a shorted turn or is fatally overloaded.

The reverse leakage of the diodes in BR1 is quite low at room temperature and the electrolytic capacitor (perhaps 10,000uF rated at 16VDC) itself typically has not much leakage, so the charge can be maintained for minutes or more with nothing connected.

More modern switching supplies (as well as linear regulated adapters) typically drain down much faster.

---

If you're connecting such an adapter to a circuit of your own making, it's worth remembering this as the adapter can easily hold enough charge to destroy something if it's connected incorrectly. With it pulled out of the wall socket, you can short the output with a wire and most of the charge will be removed, but a bit of voltage will creep back due to the way capacitors behave (dielectric absorption effect).

Answer (score 3):

Almost any DC power supply will have a capacitor on the output side, whether it's a switching converter, linear regulated, or unregulated rectifier supply. The capacitor makes the voltage more stable and helps the power supply respond to quick changes in the load, and in switching designs is entirely necessary to have a DC rather than pulsed output.

With a small load such as a voltmeter or LED, the remaining charge in the capacitor can last quite a bit longer than it would if connected to a load of the rated 700 mA.

Some supplies might have a "bleeder" resistor across the capacitor, so that it will discharge even without a load rather than lingering.